# Unable to maintain previous value of variable into another variable in C?

Tags: c

I have tried to make demo code of my actual code. I am having 2 gloabal variables prevValue and currentValue . After some time interval value of "currentValues" may get change (either x, y or z).

My aim is to **maintain value of "currentValue" variable from earlier stage(N-1) into "prevValue" variable in the current stage(N)** and so on. for example , suppose I am in stage 3, so I want to store value of "currentValue" variable from earlier stage2 i.e. 50 into stage3 "prevValue" variable.  But I am not getting expected result. So how do I correct it?

Expected output

stage1: prevSt = 10 and currentSt =10

stage2: prevSt = 10 and currentSt =50

stage3: prevSt = 50 and currentSt =10

stage4: prevSt = 10 and currentSt =70

stage5: prevSt = 70 and currentSt =50

Actual output

stage1: prevSt = 10 and currentSt =10

stage2: prevSt = 10 and currentSt =50

stage3: prevSt = 10 and currentSt =10

stage4: prevSt = 10 and currentSt =70

stage5: prevSt = 10 and currentSt =50

**NOTE:** Store or maintain the value of the variable in the sense that I want to use previous value of variable from the earlier stage into the current one till that stage only. (when there is stage 2 going on I want previous value from stage 1 , when there is stage 3 going on I want previous value from stage 2 and so on). Also there is no concern whether we write the logic for this into the same main function or separate function like I have written above

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int prevValue,currentValue;
int prevStateValue(int x, int y, int z, int pValue ,int cValue)
{
    if(cValue != pValue && cValue == x)
    {
        if(pValue == y)
        {
            pValue = y;
        }
        else
        {
            pValue = z;
        }
    }
    else if(cValue != pValue && cValue == y)
    {
        if(pValue == x)
        {
            pValue = x;
        }
        else
        {
            pValue = z;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(pValue == x)
        {
            pValue = x;
        }
        else
        {
            pValue = y;
        }
    }
    return pValue;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x ,y,z;
    x=10;
    y=50;
    z=70;

//stage 1
    currentValue = x;
    prevValue = currentValue ;
    sleep(1);
    prevValue = prevStateValue(10 ,50 ,70 ,prevValue ,currentValue);
    printf("stage1: prevSt = %d and currentSt =%d\n\r",prevValue,currentValue);

//stage 2   
    currentValue = y;
    sleep(1);
    prevValue = prevStateValue(10 ,50 ,70 ,prevValue ,currentValue);
    printf("stage2: prevSt = %d and currentSt =%d\n\r",prevValue,currentValue);

//stage 3
    currentValue = x;
    sleep(2);
    prevValue = prevStateValue(10 ,50 ,70 ,prevValue ,currentValue);
    printf("stage3: prevSt = %d and currentSt =%d\n\r",prevValue,currentValue);

//stage 4
    currentValue = z;
    sleep(1);
    prevValue = prevStateValue(10 ,50 ,70 ,prevValue ,currentValue);
    printf("stage4: prevSt = %d and currentSt =%d\n\r",prevValue,currentValue);

//stage 5
    currentValue = y;
    sleep(1);
    prevValue = prevStateValue(10 ,50 ,70 ,prevValue ,currentValue);
    printf("stage5: prevSt = %d and currentSt =%d\n\r",prevValue,currentValue);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use a debugger and see what happens with yout code...

Comment: can you Show your  output and expected output

Comment: @ferdepe  i think issue is in the prevStateValue function and also  i am not able to pass previous stage value of "currentValue" into the function

Comment: @user3559780 Why do you use prevValue and currentValue as global? You could declare the inside prevStateValue as static to preserve is value. Seeing your code, I recommend you to use global variables whenever necessary, and this is not the case. I would also add a proper naming for indicating that is a global variable and add the static identifier before the type.

Comment: @user3559780 I think you should rethink and refactor your coding. You should also search about when and how to use C global variables :)

Comment: @Srilakshmikanthan added the outputs

Comment: @ferdepe sir as said in my question this is just demo code for one  big code .Also there variables were globally declared .so I took them as it is. This is a later part i can make it out . My more focus is  to get the expected value.

Comment: `int prevStateValue(int x, int y, int z, int pValue ,int cValue)
{ return cValue; }`? I don't understand - where do you want to "store" the information about the previous value? Just move the `printf` after `currentValue =` assignment.

Comment: @KamilCuk store or maintain the value in the sense , I want to use previous value of variable from the earlier stage into the current stage till that stage only. (when there is stage 2 going on I want previous value from stage 1 , when there is stage 3 going on I want previous value from stage 2 and so on). Also there is no concern whether we write the logic for this into the same main function or separate function like I have written above

Answer (score 1):

Even if I do not understand at all your code, add line `prevValue = currentValue ;` before each stage.

```
int main(void)
{
    int x ,y,z;
    x=10;
    y=50;
    z=70;

//stage 1
    currentValue = x;
    prevValue = currentValue ;
    prevValue = prevStateValue(10 ,50 ,70 ,prevValue ,currentValue);
    printf("stage1: prevSt = %d and currentSt =%d\n\r",prevValue,currentValue);

//stage 2
    prevValue = currentValue ;
    currentValue = y;
    prevValue = prevStateValue(10 ,50 ,70 ,prevValue ,currentValue);
    printf("stage2: prevSt = %d and currentSt =%d\n\r",prevValue,currentValue);

//stage 3
    prevValue = currentValue ;
    currentValue = x;
    prevValue = prevStateValue(10 ,50 ,70 ,prevValue ,currentValue);
    printf("stage3: prevSt = %d and currentSt =%d\n\r",prevValue,currentValue);

//stage 4
    prevValue = currentValue ;
    currentValue = z;
    prevValue = prevStateValue(10 ,50 ,70 ,prevValue ,currentValue);
    printf("stage4: prevSt = %d and currentSt =%d\n\r",prevValue,currentValue);

//stage 5
    prevValue = currentValue ;
    currentValue = y;
    prevValue = prevStateValue(10 ,50 ,70 ,prevValue ,currentValue);
    printf("stage5: prevSt = %d and currentSt =%d\n\r",prevValue,currentValue);

return 0;
}
```

But you could simplify it a lot !!! Let me know